# Linux boot fails with /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXX does not exist - Asus Zenbook Pro Touchpad Not Working

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 15.10, fstab

Device: [Asus Zenbook Pro ux501vw-ds71t](http://store.asus.com/us/item/201511AM230002951/A17602)

Ubuntu Version: 15.10

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 and the installation was successful. However, the Elantech touchpad did not work. I read that the newer **4.5.0-040500RC7-generic** Kernel has added support for this touchpad and so I installed the 64bit newer kernel following the instructions [here](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/03/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-5-rc7-in-linux.html):

After the installation, I did a reboot and I get the following error(s):

```
nouveau 0000:01:00:0: priv: HUB0: 10ecc0 fffffffff
nouveau 0000:01:00:0: DRM: Pointer to TDMS table invalid
nouveau 0000:01:00:0: DRM: Pointer to flat panel table invalid
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX does not exist. Dropping ot a shell

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash(
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

I am able to boot if I switch back to the original **4.2.0.16-generic** kernel that was installed initially. The problem is only with the new kernel.

Would appreciate advice on one of the following:

1. Getting the new kernel to work - so I can check if the touchpad works
2. Getting the touchpad to work on the older kernel